# Can't invoke URL on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm a noob at Java & PHP, I don't understand how this doesn't work.
What I want to do is when I press a button in my Android app I want this PHP script to be executed:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("x","x","x"); // host, username, password...
    mysql_select_db("x"); // db name...

    $id=$_GET["id"];
    $status=$_GET["status"];

    mysql_query("UPDATE list SET status = $status WHERE id = $id");

    mysql_close();

?>
```

and this is what is supposed to trigger it:

```
public void insertDataToDB(int id, int status) {
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/SetStatus.php?id=" + id + "&status=" + status);
        Log.d("link", "http://10.0.2.2/SetStatus.php?id=" + id + "&status=" + status);
        httpclient.execute(httpget);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("insertDataToDB", "ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is my error message:

> 23:40:51.270: insertDataToDB(1914): ERROR : null

I've tried using both HttpGet and HttpPost as well as _GET and _POST in the php script, but nothing seems to work so I just stuck with _GET as the script works when i write the link into my browser. I need help, thanks in advance! :)

(it does not make any difference if i cast id & status to strings nor if i set them to constant values.)

**UPDATE**

Error log:

```
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at com.example.fibergruppenlista.DataBase.insertDataToDB(DataBase.java:34)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at com.example.fibergruppenlista.ListClickListener$2.onClick(ListClickListener.java:47)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:160)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-15 00:05:57.700: E/insertDataToDB(2080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I tried using an `asynctask<void, void, void>` but I can't get it to work, the `insertDataToDB` method is by the way not located inside of the MainActivity.java class.

Comment: What do you see if you change `Log.e("insertDataToDB", "ERROR : " + e.getMessage());` to `Log.e("insertDataToDB", "ERROR : " + e.getMessage(), e);`?

Comment: Where is your `httpclient` instantiated?

Comment: @isim it's in the class like this: private HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

Comment: @BackSlash This is what i get: http://pastebin.com/GpMREAhV

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Java or PHP. On Android, you cannot perform network operations in the main thread (the UI thread). I suggest you to run your code in an `AsyncTask` for instance. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/938081) with an example code.

Look at the official Android [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) documentation and at [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) to keep your app responsive.

Comment: I have another method which returns info from my database and it works fine, are you sure i need an asynctask? thanks.

Comment: Your method `insertDataToDB` is called from the main Thread in which you cannot perform any network operations (`NetworkOnMainThreadException`). Using an `AsyncTask` is the easiest way to solve your issue.